# google api signin promise not working on failure

Tags: javascript, promise, google-authentication

I'm using google api to authenticate the users as follows:

```
auth2.signIn().then(function(){
    //success
}, function(){
    // error
});
```

Calling above function opens google authentication window. When I click the X to close the window I expect the error function to be called but nothing is called and I don't know that the window was closed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Any errors in your developer tools console?

Comment: No no errors - nothing happens